Disable the first click on a button
I am trying to make a linked button only enable after the first click.
We have had issues with users clicking a button on accident while scrolling on mobile and are firing an event on the button click so I am trying to hack a solution that prevents users accidentally clicking the button while scrolling thererfore only enabling it after the first click.
='+1-888-888-8888';
